# Grails 2.0 use configuration value from external file in POGO

Tags: grails, grails-config

Here is the scenario.  I have an file outside of my Grails application that contains url/username/password/etc. information so that developers can not see the connection information for production.  I'm including this information in the Config.groovy by doing:

```
grails.config.locations << "file:" + "C:/directory/from/env/variable/data.properties"
```

Then I was accessing this information in a POGO via:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
...
ConfigurationHolder.config.url
ConfigurationHolder.config.userName
ConfigurationHolder.config.password
```

After upgrading to Grails 2.0 I noticed that the ConfigurationHolder is deprecated.  So I went to the documentation: ( http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html) to try and figure out how to fix it.  The documentation says to use the grailsApplication to get a hold of config values.  My problem is that I'm in a POGO and the Grails autowiring of the grailsApplication does not get invoked.  My question has 2 parts:

1) Is there a better way to get configuration information out of a file while inside of a POGO?

2) If there isn't a better way, how do I inject the grailsApplication into a POGO?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
I'm using the Grails GLDAPO plugin ( http://gldapo.codehaus.org/) to interface with an LDAP directory.  I'm trying to make these objects (which I've placed under /src/groovy) act the same way as domain objects in that I can have static methods on them to do `findBy...(..)`.  With the pattern that you're suggesting I'd HAVE to go through a service to fetch data.  Which isn't bad it's just not as Groovy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New answer based on updated question.

You have a few options. One is to wire in the `grailsApplication` to the metaclass for these classes, i.e. in `BootStrap.groovy`:

```
class BootStrap {

   def grailsApplication

   def init = { servletContext ->
      YourClass.metaClass.getGrailsApplication = { -> grailsApplication }
   }
}
```

This would add a `getGrailsApplication` method that can be accessed as the `grailsApplication` property.

Another option is to add a static `grailsApplication` field to these classes and set that in `BootStrap`:

```
class BootStrap {

   def grailsApplication

   def init = { servletContext ->
      YourClass.grailsApplication = grailsApplication
   }
}
```

Also see [this blog post](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1017) that discusses creating holder classes and [this one](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1003) that discusses overriding constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You must be calling it from an artifact that can dependency-inject the `grailsApplication` bean, at least indirectly. Add `def grailsApplication` to the service or Quartz job or whatever is calling your POGO and pass grailsApplication.config to it either for method calls that need it, or once in a setter.

Comment: thanks for your response, I added some additional information.  Could you give it a look and see if there is anyway I can avoid having to implement data access through a service?  Thanks for your feedback too btw!