# Set datasource values during run time

Tags: grails, datasource, appfog

So essentially I'm trying to get my project up and running on AppFog. The datasource information is stored in an enviornment variable, which is essentially JSON. My goal is to take this data and set my datasource config from it.

Here is what I have tried:

Code to set the datasource config which is a method in a POGO. The POGO is instantiated and the method called at the beginning of DataSource.groovy:

```
import appfog.ParseDataSource
new ParseDataSource().setConfig()

dataSource {
...
}

class ParseDataSource {

    void setConfig() {
        String env = java.lang.System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES")
        if (env) {
            def config = JSON.parse(env)
            config = config["mysql-5.1"][0].credentials
            grailsApplication.config.environments.production.dataSource.username = config.username
            grailsApplication.config.environments.production.dataSource.password = config.password
            grailsApplication.config.environments.production.dataSource.url = "jdbc:mysql://" + config.host + ":" + config.port + "/" + config.name
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that grailsApplication is always null. I've tried registering a spring bean in resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    parseDataSource(appfog.ParseDataSource) {
        grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
    }
}

class ParseDataSource {
    def grailsAPplication
    ...
}
```

I've also tried getting it via Holders:

```
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication = Holders.grailsApplication
```

Either way it is null so I'm not doing something right. Any ideas?

Comment: Classes instantiated manually with `new` do not participate in bean autowiring.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making this overly complex. Overwriting the grails config object while still in the process of building it would cause an order of operations issue that would make the code very fragile.

Simply setting the values directly seems more straightforward:

Datasource.groovy:

```
def configJson = JSON.parse(java.lang.System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"))
def mysqlConfig = configJson["mysql-5.1"][0].credentials

dataSource = {
    production = {
        username = mysqlConfig.username
        // etc.
    }
}
```

If you wanted to keep parsing in its own class for clarity's sake, make the values properties and read them in the `dataSource` block rather than trying to put them in the grails config object:

config parsing:

```
class EnvironmentConfigParser {
    String username
    String password
    String url

    EnvironmentConfigParser() {
        def configJson = JSON.parse(java.lang.System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"))
        def mysqlConfig = configJson["mysql-5.1"][0].credentials

        username = mysqlConfig.username
        password = mysqlConfig.password
        url = "jdbc:mysql://${mysqlConfig.host}:${mysqlConfig.port}/${mysqlConfig.name}"
    }
}
```

in Datasource.groovy:

```
def parser = new EnvironmentConfigParser()

dataSource = {
    production = {
        username = parser.username
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Great.. Simple and logical. One question, can BeanPostProcessor be useful in this scenario?

Comment: Probably, but you'd be changing the bean's configuration after it had been instantiated, which seems very roundabout in this case.

Comment: `java.lang.System.getenv` can be shortened to `System.getenv`.  See: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access `grailsApplication` the way you have injected in resources.groovy provided you are injecting the bean `parseDataSource` somewhere in your application in any artefact.

In your special case you need the bean to be available in `datasource.groovy`. You were instantiating the POGO which will not help you injecting `grailsApplication` to the POGO. On the other hand, you cannot actually inject the POGO to `datasource.groovy` like

`def parseDataSource`

because it(datasource) is a config object during bootstrap.

The best way remains will be to `metaClass` the pogo at `BootStrap` and make `grailsApplication` available to it. Burt has [shown it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943916/2051952) exactly that way.

I was also thinking whether [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) can be useful in this case but I am not sure whether config per environment will be achieved. But you can give it a try if it helps in achieving your business need. It generally goes like:

```
//src/groovy
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor
class DatasourcePostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor{
    def parseDataSource
    @Override
    Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        return bean
    }

    @Override
    Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        if(beanName == 'dataSource') {
           //Set values to dataSource bean as required
           parseDataSource.setConfig(bean) 
        }
        return bean
    }
}

//resources.groovy
parseDataSource(ParseDataSource){
    grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
}

datasourcePostProcessor(DatasourcePostProcessor){
    parseDataSource = ref('parseDataSource')
}
```

Comment: The problem doing it in Bootstrap is the datasource is already loaded at that point, thus changing the config will have no effect

Comment: Yup missed that piece while tailoring the answer. Thanks for reminding me.:)