# Grails - Setting up database data from a form

Tags: database, grails, database-connection

I've been ask to create a Grails applications where the user will configure database info (DB name, username, password) from a form, then access the application, and have the option to change it whenever.

I'm very new  Grails so i'm not sure how to do it.

How could I manage to do this? I have been looking at previous questions and I think this could help, but I'm not sure: [Grails 2.4.2 - Dynamically referencing default datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543726/grails-2-4-2-dynamically-referencing-default-datasource?lq=1).

If you could refer me to some docs or provide any help, I would appreciate it.

The app currently is working with Grails 2.4.4 , Sql server and will be deploy on WebSphere.

Thanks.

Comment: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912200/set-datasource-values-during-run-time

Comment: Hi, thanks that helps, actually what i'm trying to do is exactly this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225187/grails-start-the-application-without-connecting-to-database , but i can't make it work since the answers were for an older version of grails. Any idea on how to make it work for grails 2.4.4?